# Issues with gradient descent and log trick

Tags: function, math, optimization, gradient

I am using gradient descent to minimize a function f(x) with the constraint that x is positive.

For this I used the log trick. I set x = exp(y).
Then I updated y at every iteration

> y = logx - learning_rate*gradient(f wrt y)
>
> gradient of f wrt y = gradient of f wrt x*x

However, I am seeing strange behavior. As I keep on iterating, I see that when it reaches a point, the updates don't improve the objective function but stay close. However, if I forcefully update the parameters even though it doesn't improve or minimize the objective function but instead increases it, after a while it again starts flowing nicely further decreasing the objective function.

My function is convex, so there is no local minima that could have caused this issue. Does  it have something to do with this log trick that is causing the issue?

Comment: You have an error, `gradient_of_f_wrt_y = gradient_of_f_wrt_x * x`, not `gradient_of_y_wrt_x * x`.

Comment: What happens when you don't use the "log trick"?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta. I need to make the parameters positive other it will violate other constraints for eg positive definiteness and causes issues calculating the objective function itself

Comment: Can you post the code you use? There could be some implementation error there which wouldn't know about.